# PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied (Windows Update Disabler)

Tags: python

Im having trouble with my windows update disabler script, whenever i run in in an unelevated shell i get an error `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied` but whenever i run with and elevated shell it just closes with no error. What can i do to avoid, or get rid of this error.

```
import winreg
option = input("Would you like to continue: ")
if option == ('yes'):
    medic = winreg.CreateKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\WaaSMedicSvc')
    winreg.SetValueEx(medic, 'Start', 0, winreg.REG_SZ, '4')
    medic.Close()
    wua = winreg.CreateKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\wuauserv')
    winreg.SetValueEx(wua, 'Start', 0, winreg.REG_SZ, '4')
    wua.Close()
if option == ('no'):
    exit()
else:
    print("Input Error")
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

You run it in an elevated shell.  The Services key is protected.  You know, you can make a .reg file and feed it directly to `regedit`.  That will automatically ask for elevation.